# Why are my threads hanging in this socket test on windows?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, sockets

I wrote this script to test socket behavior in Windows, and I'm not sure why it hangs in Windows and not in Ubuntu. The script makes three listening sockets bound to '127.0.0.1', and it makes 60 threads which each connect to the listening sockets 10 times, 20 threads per listening socket.

```
import threading
import socket
import logging
import os

ports = [60003, 60004, 60005]

class ServerTest(threading.Thread):
    log_lock = threading.Lock()
    def __init__(self, port):
        super(ServerTest, self).__init__(name=('socktest_%d'%port))
        self.port = port
        self._init_logger()

    def _init_logger(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
        handler = logging.FileHandler('socktest.log')
        formatter = logging.Formatter(
            '%(levelname)s -- %(asctime)s:\n%(message)s',
            datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %a')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    def log(self, junk):
        self.log_lock.acquire()
        if isinstance(junk, Exception):
            self.logger.exception(junk)
        else:
            self.logger.info(str(junk))
        self.log_lock.release()

    def run(self):
        try:
            listener = socket.socket()
            listener.bind(('127.0.0.1', self.port))
            listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            listener.listen(100)
        except Exeption as exc:
            self.log(exc)
            return

        while True:
            try:
                c, a = listener.accept()
                self.log('accepted connection from '+str(a)+' to '+self.name)
                data = c.recv(4096)
                if data == 'stop':
                    break
                self.log('data:\n'+data)
                c.sendall(data)
                c.close()
            except Exception as exc:
                self.log(exc)
        listener.close()

class ClientTest(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, port):
        super(ClientTest, self).__init__()
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        try:
            for i in range(10):
                c = socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', self.port))
                data = os.urandom(256)
                c.sendall(data)
                c.recv(256)
                c.close()
        except Exception as exc:
            return

def main():
    print 'Starting test'
    server_threads = [ServerTest(p) for p in ports]
    for thread in server_threads:
        thread.start()
        print 'started thread', thread

    client_threads = []
    for p in ports:
        for i in range(20):
            client_threads.append(ClientTest(p))
    for thread in client_threads:
        thread.start()
        print 'started thread', thread
    for thread in client_threads:
        thread.join()
        print 'joined thread', thread
    for p in ports:
        c = socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', p))
        c.sendall('stop')
        c.close()
    for thread in server_threads:
        thread.join()
        print 'joined thread', thread
    print 'Finished'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried it with and without the line `listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` and the behavior is the same. I also tried it with an without the lock and the behavior was *still* the same.

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that it *does* print out all the the threads, it seems to be stuck in the thread.join() for the client_threads, but I don't know why.

Comment: close() doesn't terminate the socket. Add `socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` to do the deed. I'm not sure if that's enough, so not writing it as an answer.

Comment: In fact, on the client, right after the sendall, add `c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` and then after the recv, do `c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)`.

Comment: You were right @tdelaney . I replaced the c.close() with c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR) and it worked. I was getting some error at the very end though, after sending stop to all the server threads and doing listener.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR). The errors went away and everything still worked when when I wrapped up the listener.shutdown in a try:... except socket.error:...

Comment: actually, leaving it as listener.close() worked without the try: ... except: ...

Comment: Yeah, shutdown is only needed for active connections, not the listener.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic powers tell me `os.urandom()` can block on Windows if there is insufficient entropy available (it should never block on Unix).  I haven't been able to confirm this one way or the other [via MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but given the reliance on hardware entropy (unlike, say, FreeBSD, which uses a pure software implementation), I don't think blocking is entirely inconceivable.  Try replacing the `os.urandom(256)` call with (say) `b'\x00' * 256`.

Comment: I tested thie with a little loop in python, where I continuously called os.urandom(256) and then print '\r'+str(i), then increment I. It never blocks